# About the right way to use Julia & Base.Test: run all tests even if some fail

Tags: unit-testing, julia

Using `Base.Test` for my unit tests, I am surprised by immediate exit right after the first test failure.

Let's consider this `runtest.jl` file:

```
using Base.Test

@testset "First" begin
    # test fails
    @test false
end;

@testset "Second" begin
    # never run... 
    @test true 
end;
```

The output of `julia runtest.jl` is always (the second test is never run):

> ```
> First: Test Failed
>   Expression: false
> Stacktrace:
>  [1] macro expansion at /home/picaud/Temp/runtests.jl:14 [inlined]
>  [2] macro expansion at ./test.jl:860 [inlined]
>  [3] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
> Test Summary: | Fail  Total
> First         |    1      1
> ERROR: LoadError: Some tests did not pass: 0 passed, 1 failed, 0 errored, 0 broken.
> ```

**My question**: how to run and report all test results even if some tests fail?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reading the Julia doc [Working-with-Test-Sets](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Test/index.html#Working-with-Test-Sets-1) it seems one must systematically use **nested testset**:

> Typically a large number of tests are used to make sure functions work
>   correctly over a range of inputs. **In the event a test fails, the
>   default behavior is to throw an exception immediately**. However, it is
>   normally preferable to run the rest of the tests first to get a better
>   picture of how many errors there are in the code being tested.

and later this quote:

> The @testset() macro can be used to group tests into sets. **All the
>   tests in a test set will be run, and at the end of the test set a
>   summary will be printed.**

In the previous peculiar example, this

```
using Base.Test

@testset "All tests" begin

    @testset "First" begin
        @test false 
    end;

    @testset "Second" begin
        # is run, ok
        @test true 
    end;

end;
```

will **run all tests:**

> ```
> First: Test Failed
>   Expression: false
> Stacktrace:
>  [1] macro expansion at /home/picaud/Temp/runtests.jl:5 [inlined]
>  [2] macro expansion at ./test.jl:860 [inlined]
>  [3] macro expansion at /home/picaud/Temp/runtests.jl:4 [inlined]
>  [4] macro expansion at ./test.jl:860 [inlined]
>  [5] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
> Test Summary: | Pass  Fail  Total
> All tests     |    1     1      2
>   First       |          1      1
>   Second      |    1            1
> ERROR: LoadError: Some tests did not pass: 1 passed, 1 failed, 0 errored, 0 broken.
> ```

Comment: there we go, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That is a loooong writeup containing a simple question in it. The answer is also simple: yes, adding an outer test set is the de-facto standard for achieving the goal.

Comment: I have shortened my Q/A.